# How should i structure a Mysql database with tabular numerical data?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have data from an extensive range of benchmarking tests and need some means of storing the data for use in a web based application the plan is to add data from new products when we conduct the tests:

1. i have some information about each product (make, model, type, market sector, notes, etc.)
2. Each product is subjected to ~20 tests usually the same core tests but occasionally more specific tests.
3. The output of each test is the same 50 channels of raw data (usually ~ 600 rows).
4. This raw data is processed to add additional calculated channels (another 25)
5. Some of the channels are processed to give smoothed interpolated data (~10 channels, ~20 rows)
6. Some single value metrics, gradients, hysteresis, ranges are extracted from the smoothed and raw data. (3000 items)
7. The smoothed data and metrics will be different dependant on the test type.

I’ve constructed one large table to keep all the product information and the single values in, where i give each product a unique name, but it's getting difficult to manage >3000 columns. Then I have 2 tables for each test (named based on test type and unique name), one for raw and calculated data, and one for smoothed interpolated data.

I’m building a web based interface using php to access the data and plot, tabulate and chart relevant information based on user selections.
Ascii data files are uploaded again through a web interface and are processed using python give the smooth data and metrics.

The problem is I’m not sure my database is constructed in the best way, I need to make it reasonably easy to change, adding tests, recording additional metrics, etc. currently that’s not so easy.

This is my first stab at all of the above tools (and my first post) and i really pleased with the initial results.  But I wanted to make sure i was going about it all the right way before going any further.

Any ideas, or advice?

Comment: No wonder it's difficult.  This design is in dire need of normalization.

Comment: `Product` sounds like a *type* of product, not the individual copies of a product. It could contain the description of a certain brand of peanutbutter, but not a record for each jar, right? Are the tests done once for such a type (brand/flavour), or one for each item (jar).

Comment: For `product` read individual vehicle. A vehicle is put on a test rig and ~20 similar tests are conducted. in each test certain (slightly different for each test) forces/displacements are applied to the vehicle and ~50 measurements are made at each force step (~600 in total). I know its an unruly beast! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of your comment "*For product read individual vehicle. A vehicle is put on a test rig and ~20 similar tests are conducted. in each test certain (slightly different for each test) forces/displacements are applied to the vehicle and ~50 measurements are made at each force step (~600 in total):*,  you would need the following tables

```
PRODUCTS
product_id
product_make
product_model
product_notes  

TESTS
test_id
test_name

PRODUCT_TESTS  (this table stores which tests are appropriate to each product)
pt_id
product_id
test_id 

MEASUREMENTS
measure_id
pt_id
force_step
value
```

Your original question lists more attributes which are not clear to me. At least the above should be enough to get you started, after which you add more fields and tables.